# How to let the outside world decorate my private field?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, decorator

Imagine a simple `Controller`  (as in process control) interface. I have some concrete classes, say `PIDController`, that implement it. I also have some decorator classes that extend these classes somehow, say `ITAETuningDecorator`.

Now imagine that a `FloodGate` class has a private `Controller` field. I would like, from the outside and at runtime, to attach to the `Controller` in `FloodGate` an `ITAETuningDecorator`. How can I do it? I have no access to the field from the outside and obviously the decorator needs a reference to the original controller to be built.

Comment: Could you add a `FloodGate.DecorateController(ControllerDecoratorFactory factory)` method which would do something like `{ this.controller = factory.Create(this.controller); }` ?

Comment: Oh actually that's a pretty neat idea. So basically I just pass to the floodgate a function controller-->decoratedController and let it deal with it, correct?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "attach a Decorator" ? Do you want the decorated version to stick in the FloodGate permanently or wouldn't you be just fine with an ephemeral decorated Controller ?

Comment: I'd like the private field in FloodGate to point to the decorator rather than the concrete class being decorated. I suppose that's your definition of stick permanently, right?
Anyway @MetaFight, your solution works just fine. If you write it in an answer I'll choose it as best answer and be done with it.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, but why would you do that ? It's pretty rare to have to replace an existing instance of something with a subclass of it at runtime, that's why I'm asking. It might be legitimate in some cases, but might be a design smell as well.

Answer (score 3):

The question is: Who instantiates the `Controller`?

- If it's created outside the `FloodGate` instance, you can wrap it there and pass the wrapped instance into the `FloodGate`.
- If it's created by the `FloodGate` internally (which seems strange to me, but I'm not into your domain), you could either change that and pass it in (e.g. as a constructor parameter) or add a method `addControllerDecorator(Controller c)` to the `FloodGate`. The latter implies that you can instantiate the wrapper and later set the instance it wraps, which looks like a poor design choice to me...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My real problem is not so much at instantiation. I'd like to decorate my Controller long after it has been instantiated and has been used for a while.

Comment: Ok, but you need to keep the same `FloodGate` instance? Then you could do something like `floodGate.setController(new Wrapper(floodGate.getController()))` to add the wrapper. Alternatively, you create a new `FloodGate` and pass it the wrapped controller from the old gate.

Comment: @CarrKnight: So you want to effectively replace the Controller used by a Floodgate?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau not really. The underlying controller has to stay. I just want to attach a decorator to it to adjust its behavior on a need basis, but I don't want to lose the state of the original concrete Controller.
I am afraid i will have to use getter/setter which is annoying because I really don't want to let any reference to the private field out. Sure beats cloning the floodgate everytime.

Comment: @CarrKnight: How about this scheme: `Floodgate` has references to *two* controllers, a bare bones one and a decorated version, and provides methods to switch between them. Optionally, the `Floodgate` can even be unaware that the two controllers are related and only the instantiating logic dictates that a `Floodgate` gets a `Controller` and a decorator wrapped around that same `Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

The "outside world" code could use reflection (the nasty kind) to access and / or update the private field.

But a better idea (IMO) would modify your APIs to provide access to the fields that you want to decorate.  This could take the form of a getters and / or setters, or it could be more specialized methods that add and (if necessary) remove the decorations.  In short "decoratibility" should be part of the API.